# Neo4J search greater than on Index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J database with a large number of datasets (~15M), where I want to perform a greater than search on one of its properties. I have the corresponding property indexed. The property is a float value.

When I do an exact match like `MATCH (i:Label) WHERE i.property = $value RETURN count(i)` I get the result within a very short time. But when I do the same search with `greater than`, i.e. `MATCH (i:Label) WHERE i.property > $value RETURN count(i)` it just takes forever. What is the correct way to do this in Cypher?

Edit: Execution plan:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
74 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

EagerAggregation
  |
  +Filter
    |
    +NodeByLabelScan

+------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+    
|         Operator | EstimatedRows | Identifiers |                        Other |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| EagerAggregation |          2064 |    count(r) |                              |
|           Filter |       4260557 |           r | r.date > Subtract(Divide(    |
|                  |               |             | TimestampFunction(),{        |  
|                  |               |             | AUTOINT0}),Literal(86400))   |
|  NodeByLabelScan |      14201858 |           r |                     :Request |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

Comment: Please show us execution plan of the query - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to create additional/aggregation nodes for that property and searching thru those nodes.

**Example**

Let say the property is a value from 0 - 100.

Create following nodes
 * 0to30
 * 31to60
 * 61to100

Create relationship from you nodes to this 'aggregate' nodes.

Than searching thru those nodes

MATCH (l:Label)-[i:IN]->(a:0to30)
RETURN l

Comment: Thanks, that has been a very great input. Sometimes I'm just too blind to see the obvious

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Neo4j doesn't use it's indexes for inequalities in 2.2.x.  In the upcoming 2.3.x this should be supported.

Comment: I was expecting something like that :( Is there any information on when 2.3.x is supposed to be released?

Comment: And is this feature already implemented in the Milestone release?

Comment: It's planned for 2.3.0-M03 which should hopefully be out in the near future.  Feel free to test it when it comes out, but remember that milestone releases don't guarantee an upgrade path for your database when the next milestone/release candidate comes out.